# How to categorize customers based on number of transactions they've done in previous months?

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table that looks like follows:

| CustomerID | Month | Total transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 12 | 5 |
| 2 | 11 | 1 |
| 2 | 11 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 13 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

CustomerID is the unique identifier for a customer. The table provides the total number of transactions done by a customer for every month in the year. Months are represented as numbers ranging from 1 to 12 with 1 representing January and 12 representing December. If no transaction has been done by a customer in a specific month, there is no data row captured corresponding to that specific month for the customer in question.

I wish to create another column 'Category' which categorises each customerID to one of the categories defined as follows:

1. If a customerID has 1 or more Total transactions in December and no transactions in previous months, then category should be 'A'
2. If a customer has 1 or more Total transactions in December and 3 or more cumulative transactions in September, October and November then category should be 'B'
3. If a customer has 5 or more cumulative transactions in January to June, then category should be 'C'

A simple GROUP BY on CustomerID followed by SUM(Total transactions) doesn't seem to help in creating the categorisations I want. I am unable to think of how to construct a query or approach this problem.

Any help would be really appreciated.

PS: I am trying to implement this in Impala so HiveQL may be the appropriate language.

Comment: Is month really stored as a string?  That makes everything more cumbersome.

Comment: Actually it isn’t! I had written it as a string here on Stack Overflow just to make the presentation better. I have edited the question to represent months as numbers, which is how they actually are represented in the actual data set that I am working with.

Comment: I have also edited the condition presented in point number 3 above from 1 or more transactions to 5 or more transactions, to bring more generality to any answers.